# Buscar no MySQL usando somente dia, mês ou ano com PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, datetime

Criei uma tabela, nela um campo no formato *DATETIME* para armazenar o *dia, mês, ano e horário* em que um registro é feito.

**Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer para buscar somente usando dia, mês ou ano ?**

**Exemplo:**

Tenho 4 registros:

```
 2017-02-03
 2017-02-13
 2017-05-03
 2018-01-04
```

Ao fazer uma busca para exibir os registros feitos no dia 03, deve aparecer assim:

```
 2017-02-03
 2017-05-03
```

Ao fazer uma busca para exibir os registros feitos no ano 2017, deve aparecer assim:

```
 2017-02-03
 2017-02-13
 2017-05-03
```

A mesma coisa deve ser feita para o mês.É possível fazer isso com PHP?

Comment: João, deu certo? Teria algo mais que posso lhe ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize: `YEAR(), MONTH() e DAY()`:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela
WHERE YEAR(data) = '2017'
AND MONTH(data) = '07'
AND DAY(data) IN ('1', '25' , '30')
```

Direto no PHP com `explode`:

```
$data = '2017-01-15';

$arrayData = explode("-", $data);

echo "Ano:     ".$arrayData[0];
echo "<br>Mes: ".$arrayData[1];
echo "<br>Dia: ".$arrayData[2];
```